# How to change elements of matrix

Tags: r

I have a this matrix:

```
count.data <-  matrix(data = 1, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
                    print(count.data)
```

and then want sample 2 to have double the amount of counts for each gene:

```
count.data[2, ] <- count.data[2, ]*2
```

What I am struggling with is that I now want to change the matrix such that sample 3 has the following counts for each gene (32,16,8,4,2). I don't know how to do this, I thought that maybe I could just write

```
count.data <- count.data[3, ]*32                                                  
              count.data[3, ]*16                                                                     
                      .                                                                       
                      .                                                           
              count.data[3, ]*2
```

but that doesn't work. How can I do this? Thankful for all help!

Comment: `count.data[3, ]*2^(5:1)`?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thank you very much! If I'd want to calculate the mean value of each gene and store this as a vector, how could I do this. I tried: m1 <- mean(count.data[[1:3,1]]) but that doesn't work. This is the first time I am using RStudio so I don't know much yet..

Comment: You'll get better help if you edit your question to give an example of your input and the desired output, bonus points for showing what you've tried to achieve it.